# Uncaught ReferenceError: Bloodhound is not defined : typeahead 0.11.1

Tags: typeahead.js, bloodhound

Recently I upgraded to typeahead to 0.11.1. After that I have started getting the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: Bloodhound is not defined".
We use require js multiple javascript modules and typeahead is also being packaged in one of those modules. I have tried using the typeahead .bundle.js as well as  bloodhound.js and typeahead.jquery.js independantly. Still the error persists. With the old typeahead version everything was working fine.

Comment: Look at this link. This helped me before we restructured our gulp config.  https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/1211